# Gradle: how to zip/tar output from other zip/tar task?

Tags: gradle

I have a project that has a task called `shadowDistTar`, which is provided by the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).  The output of this task is a tar file.

I wish to create another Tar task that will include the output tar file into a new tar file, containing the first tar file and some new files.  However, I cannot get the tar file to be included in new archive.

```
task("myNewTarTask", type: Tar) {
    // configure the Tar task here...

    project.afterEvaluate {

        // we put things in afterEvaluate so the outputs of shadowDistTar are known
        dependsOn shadowDistTar

        shadowDistTar.getOutputs().getFiles().each {
            include it.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

I think the issue here is that the `include` should take an ANT style include spec, which should be relative to the source directory of the Tar task, rather than absolute paths, which is what I get with `getOutputs()`.  How can I either get the outputs as an ANT style include, or otherwise include the tar file created by `shadowDistTar` into the second tar, without resorting to hard-coding the path into the include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Project.tarTree(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#tarTree-java.lang.Object-). Eg:

```
task("myNewTarTask", type: Tar) {
   dependsOn shadowDistTar
   from tarTree(shadowDistTar.archiveFile)
   from 'path/to/extra/files'    
}
```